# Redirected Domain Problem

Tags: html

We have 2 different websites. One is xy.com another is xyz.com. The domain xyz.com is redirected to a folder on xy.com\one

This works fine. Now we want a particular link to be opened (for example, www.xyz.com\abc.html). I am placing this file in xy.com\one\abc.html. But when I enter this url, it takes me to home page, instead of abc.html. Though I can open abc.html, by entering www.xy.com\one\abc.html.

I need to open this file, from link, www.xyz.com\abc.html. How to accomplish this??

Regards,
Rahul Jain

Comment: Can you post the webserver (IIS? Apache?) you are using? And what kind of web technology are you using (Asp.net? PHP?)

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is your slashes are reversed. Did you keep your url's near a strong magnet?

Comment: My slashes are reversed, because I can never put them correctly. But they are otherwise correct in the pages and everywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using apache you might want to have a look at mod_rewrite. There are similar methods available for other servers.

Would be good to know which environment you are using (web server and server side language) and if you are applying the re-direct rules in a programmatic way or via server configuration.

Comment: We have simply redirected the domain to this folder, by configuring it on ISP server.

Answer (score 0):

To give a serious reply, there could be several things wrong in the redirect.

1. You have to setup a redirect from the old domain to the new, by using a .htaccess on the old domain, changing the DNS records for the domain, or probably some other alternatives. Which of these have you used?
2. In case of the second option the receiving server (xy.com) has to accept the incoming domain (xyz.com). When I set my DNS records for a domain to go to a certain server, I have to actually setup the server to accept that domain, usually by "parking" it in Cpanel. Some hosts charge per parked domain, which is why they don't accept the incoming traffic automatically.
3. Depending on the method used, the receiving server has to be told what to do with the request.

So most importantly: *HOW* did you set up the redirect? Was it a DNS record? Was it a htaccess on the side of xy.com? Any other methods? (sorry, this isn't really an answer either but it was too long for the comments)